# How to redirect to different pages upon Login in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I created a registration page where there is a drop down menu that allows to user to select a user type (`Tutor` or `Student`).

They'll be redirected to Login page and they should be redirected to different pages depending on the type.

**AccountController.cs**

```
[HttpPost] //"Login" Button
public ActionResult Login(UsersModel record)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetConnection()))
    {
        con.Open();
        string query = @"SELECT UserID, TypeID FROM Users WHERE Email=@Email AND Password=@Password AND Status!=@Status";


        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", record.Email);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", record.Password);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "Suspended");

            using (SqlDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (data.HasRows)
                {

                    while (data.Read())
                    {
                        Session["userid"] = data["UserID"].ToString();
                        Session["typeid"] = data["TypeID"].ToString();
                    }

                    if ((string)Session["typeid"] == "Student")

                        return RedirectToAction("Profile");

                    if ((string)Session["typeid"] == "Tutor")

                        return RedirectToAction("TutorProfile");
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Error = "<div class = alert alert-danger col-lg-6'>Invalid Credentials.</div>";
                    return View();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Visual Studio, I am getting the error:

> "not all code paths return value"

Doesn't the `return RedirectToAction` count as return value?

Comment: The 2 redirect returns are for the preceding if conditions.
For `if (data.HasRows){}` you need to specify another one

Comment: @Chocolate - Hello, can I help you further?

Answer (score 0):

The [Compiler Error CS0161](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0161) *"not all code paths return value"* is referring to the commented portion I've noted below as `// HERE`.

It's saying, if the two `IF` conditions are `FALSE`, what am I supposed to `return`?

I've wrapped braces around the statements to help describe what I mean.

```
if (data.HasRows)
{
    while (data.Read())
    {
        Session["userid"] = data["UserID"].ToString();
        Session["typeid"] = data["TypeID"].ToString();
    }

    if ((string)Session["typeid"] == "Student")
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Profile");
    }

    if ((string)Session["typeid"] == "Tutor")
    {
        return RedirectToAction("TutorProfile");
    }

    // HERE
}
```

Comment: Hello! I tried all the solutions here but when I click "Login" it stays on the same login page.

Answer (score 0):

What if typeid is neither Student or Tutor?

Consider either:

```
if ((string)Session["typeid"] == "Student")
    return RedirectToAction("Profile");
else if ((string)Session["typeid"] == "Tutor")
    return RedirectToAction("TutorProfile");
```

or:

```
if ((string)Session["typeid"] == "Student")
    return RedirectToAction("Profile");
if ((string)Session["typeid"] == "Tutor")
    return RedirectToAction("TutorProfile");
ViewBag.Error = "<div class = alert alert-danger col-lg-6'>Invalid User Type.</div>";
return View();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look the changes below.

```
string sRedirecttoAction = String.Empty;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetConnection()))
{
    con.Open();
    string query = @"SELECT UserID, TypeID FROM Users WHERE Email=@Email AND Password=@Password AND Status!=@Status";


    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", record.Email);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", record.Password);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "Suspended");

        using (SqlDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (data.HasRows)
            {

                while (data.Read())
                {
                    Session["userid"] = data["UserID"].ToString();
                    Session["typeid"] = data["TypeID"].ToString();
                }

                if ((string)Session["typeid"] == "Student")

                    sRedirecttoAction = "Profile";

                if ((string)Session["typeid"] == "Tutor")

                    sRedirecttoAction = "TutorProfile";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Error = "<div class = alert alert-danger col-lg-6'>Invalid Credentials.</div>";
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}

//return RedirectToAction here.
return RedirectToAction(sRedirecttoAction);
```

Answer (score -1):

**The error appears to be in the code below.  I revised that part of your code. 
 Try that and see if that works**

```
if (data.HasRows)
                {

                    while (data.Read())
                    {
                        Session["userid"] = data["UserID"].ToString();
                        Session["typeid"] = data["TypeID"].ToString();
                    }

                    //make sure there is no space between these two lines
                    if ((string)Session["typeid"] == "Student")
                      return RedirectToAction("Profile");

                    //make sure there is no space between these two lines
                    if ((string)Session["typeid"] == "Tutor")
                        return RedirectToAction("TutorProfile");

                    //###if those two if clauses are not met, there is no return after that.
                    return view(); //? or something else
                }
```